# PCB component with abbreviation SR1

Tags: components, surface-mount

I have a laptop battery pack with a fried component (visually fried) that has the appearance of a large surface mount resistor (only 2 connectors). It has the PCB abbreviation next to it of "SR1" which I have not been able to identify. It also has "R010" and "FZ67" on it, though I haven't been able to find a component matching those part numbers either. One side of it connects directly to one end of the battery pack.

How do I identify this part?

Comment: Can you post an image of the relevant PCB area?

Comment: "SR" static relay ?

Comment: The question would be easier to answer, if you add a photo of the component on the board.

Comment: @Markus, a picture, and possibly a schematic (self drawn) would help. R010 could refer to a 0.01Ω Resistor, as a "Series Resistor" or "Shunt Resistor" for voltage and current sensing. But most resistors only have one code, not two on them. So a picture is a must here.

Comment: Dear reader, please ignore the accepted answer and look at Dave Tweed's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"SR" could an abbreviation of Silicon Rectifier. Its a 2 terminal component and could have the size of a smd resistor.

Its look like this:

[image]

Here are some examples of components: [1](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/109995/DCCOM/SM5391.html), [2](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/310536/PACELEADER/SM5399.html), [3](http://luguang.manufacturer.globalsources.com/si/6008817164497/pdtl/Rectifier/1071953951/Silicon-Rectifiers-SOD-123FL.htm), [4](http://www.ec21.com/product-details/Silicon-Controlled-Rectifier-Diode-S2A--5013061.html)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks to all for your responses and help (sorry I didn't know this forum was aimed mainly at design, so I'll keep than in mind for the future, I'll also remember diagrams and/or photos). I think Butzke has hit the nail on the head, that's exactly how it looks and suits its location in circuit. Thanks for a great and detailed answer.

Comment: That being said, before getting a replacement, I'll draw the circuit to ensure it's not a resistor for voltage monitoring as previously suggested. Thanks again.

Comment: @Markus If the answer was right please consider to mark as answered.

Comment: @Markus those packages are used for multiple types of devices. Diodes, Resistors, chip inductors, fuses, etc.

Comment: This is almost certainly wrong. There would be no reason to connect such a diode directly to one terminal of a battery pack.

Answer (score 5):

Shunt resistor, 0.010 ohms, common on laptop battery PCB.

Comment: Agreed - the reported component marking "R010" fits with this answer.

Comment: ...and this is what happens when the OP decides which answer is "best"...